# Windows Form control not working properly in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I have a Windows Form with progress bar, the progress bar working fine when I open the form in Windows Application, now we are migrating our windows application to wpf application. We are doing this migration step-by-step, we are following below procedure in migration.

- Created new C# WPF application project.
- Re-designed some important windows form as WPF window (MetroWindow from MahApps)
- Added the existing Windows form application in WPF app's project reference.
- Now, we are opening a existing project's windows form in new WPF app.

In this way, the windows form that included the progress bar control not showing progress when I open the form in WPF application.

Can anyone help me to overcome this situation?

Comment: How exactly "not showing properly"?

Comment: Can you show a code how you open a windows form? Are you sure this is a "Controls" problem, not a logic which running process

Comment: I am just using the form's instance to open:                                                                             MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();

Comment: If form shown successfully, then I think the problem is inside of that Form and have nothing to do with WPF. Does form using some global variables?

Comment: Hi @Fabio , no this form just contains progress control alone..used to show progress.

Comment: Then I afraid you need to show some code which starts and update progressbar

Comment: Hi @Fabio, the same progress bar with same code working fine in Windows Application...but it is not working only in WPF Application. You can easily reproduce this issue by creating form with progress bar control in Windows Application and referencing this form in WPF app.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the method of [Hosting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.100).aspx) there is some walkthroughs about that...

Comment: Or it is better to use this tutorial using XAML
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752027(v=vs.100).aspx

WPF and WFs have base classes for such common components, like Button, TextBox, etc. It should help to you.